# How to build a client to do oauth 1.0 authentication with signature method as HMAC-SHA256?

Tags: c#, rest, dll, httpclient

I had got something working with HMAC-SHA1 using Oauth.dll which has a direct functions of signature methods. But now our customer is changing everything to HMACSHA-256 and I am not able to find any new dll which supports this signature method .
Can any one point me to a correct direction please ?

```
OAuthRequest client = OAuthRequest.ForProtectedResource("POST", ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, TokenID, Tokensecret);
                            client.RequestUrl = webserviceURl;
                           client.Realm = AccountId;
                            
                         **client.SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1;**
                            
                            
                            //// add HTTP header authorization
                           string auth = client.GetAuthorizationHeader();
                            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(client.RequestUrl);
                            request.ContentType = "application/json";
                            request.Method = "POST";
                           request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);


                            ////attach the body of json 

                            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                            {
                                string json = jsonvalue;

                                streamWriter.Write(json);
                            }
```

Comment: If there isn't a library for it, your best option would seem to be to fork the library you're currently using, assuming the licence is compatible.

Comment: Hi Llama,
Th current DLL does not allow mw to change the signature type as it is not inbuilt fucntionality .(The dll just support 3 signature method -HmacSha1, PlainText , RsaSha1)

Comment: Re-read my comment. It's [this library](https://github.com/rhargreaves/oauth-dotnetcore), right? As I said in my previous comment: you could [fork it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX7Td.png) and add the functionality you require. It looks like the [licence](https://github.com/rhargreaves/oauth-dotnetcore/blob/master/LICENSE) allows for that. Alternatively, just implement Oauth 1.0 functionality for yourself completely.

Comment: Thanks Llama ,
That worked .Added few lines of code as per my requirement for HMAC-SHA256 in code and generated a new DLL altogether